# Connection between two ics

Tags: clock

A part of system contains two ics , 2nd ic inputs are outputs of 1st ic, 1st ic generates clock and some data signal. 1st ic output clock is negative edge triggered, 2nd ic clock is positive edge triggered, if I connect 1st ic negative edge clock to 2nd ic clock pin. What are the problems that system will face?

Comment: Everything that the timing diagrams reveal.

Comment: A schematic, datasheet and some specific questions would be helpful...

Comment: Read the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/102984).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brief picture of a data and clock transmission: -

[image]

As you should be able to see data is "stable" on the rising clock edge. If you tried to read it on the negative clock edge you might read a zero when in fact the data was just about to change to a 1 or vice versa.

If your data is clocked out on the negative edge of the generated clock and read in on the positive edge of the received clock then it should be OK. Logic levels have to be the same of course and if sending the data over long tracks at too high a speed you will likely need a mechanism to stop reflections causing corruptions to clock and/or data,

Reading data on the wrong edge can sometimes work but it's usually flaky to do so.

Comment: Adding two inverters, in series with both the clock and the data would retain the timing margins, and give the clock the correct polarity.  It'd also invert all the data bits, of course.

Comment: @Whit3rd sorry dude but I don't know what you are driving at. Adding two inverters to both clock and data produces zero net effect.

Comment: The idea was, invert the data ONCE, and the clock ONCE, not to use two inverters on the data and two on the clock.   That gives the second system a valid data value at the same time as the active edge of its clock.

Comment: It's not needed because data changes on neg edge of clock and read on the positive edge if I read the question correctly.